# Modify READLINE_LINE to contain ANSI codes

Tags: bash, readline

READLINE_LINE is a special variable available to commands specified in `bind -x` readline bindings.

I have bound some keys to run custom functions with `bind -x`. In a function, I want to modify the current command and wrap it in the ANSI color code for red. Eg:

```
READLINE_LINE=$'\033[0;31m'"$READLINE_LINE"
```

No matter what I have tried, the code is printed back in the terminal as is. Is there a way to have red color printed in the terminal?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're trying to do. 
Does this help?

```
#!/bin/bash
bar=$(echo '\033[0;31m'"$READLINE_LINE"\033[m)
echo "$bar"
```

But why not just:

```
qux=foo
bar='\033[0;31m'"$qux"'\033[m'
echo "$bar"
```

Note 1: Always close a color escape sequence with the 'reset to normal' sequence `\033[m`'.

Note 2: I think whether or not this comes out as color ultimately depends on the terminal, though most virtuial terminals these can perfectly handle hundreds of colors.

Comment: I added an intro to the question. READLINE_LINE is a special bash variable.

Comment: I made an edit to my answer, does that get you on your way?   I think btw. READLINE_LINE is a 'read-only' variable.